# Parse emit TypeScript? - `const a = {foo: 'bar'}` to `const a = {foo: 'bar', can: 'haz'}`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Followed [the guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#traversing-the-ast-with-a-little-linter), got some of the way there:

```
export function delint(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile) {
  delintNode(sourceFile);

  function delintNode(node: ts.Node) {
    if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.VariableDeclaration) {
      // something
    }

    ts.forEachChild(node, delintNode);
```

How do I get the rest of the way, i.e.: adding a new thing to the object literal, then outputting the editing code with the same order of properties but a new one at the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify the source file text to add the property, then it can be done this way:

1. Get the object literal expression from the AST (using https://ts-ast-viewer.com helps to understand how the AST looks).
2. Use `ts.updateObjectLiteral` to get a new node for the old node with the new property.
3. Print out the new node's text and modify the original text with the printed node text.
4. Reparse to a new AST if necessary or just use the modified text.

Note that printing the object literal will remove any custom formatting you previously had because the printer prints nodes in its own way. You may want to run the code through prettier or some other formatter afterwards.

Example:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

// parse the AST
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile("file.ts", "const a = { foo: 'bar' };",
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, false);

// get the object literal expression
const objectLiteralExpression = sourceFile.statements.find(ts.isVariableStatement)!
    .declarationList.declarations[0].initializer as ts.ObjectLiteralExpression;

// get a transformed node with the new property and print it
const transformedOle = ts.updateObjectLiteral(objectLiteralExpression, [
    ...objectLiteralExpression.properties,
    ts.createPropertyAssignment("can", ts.createStringLiteral("haz"))
]);
const newNodeText = ts.createPrinter()
    .printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, transformedOle, sourceFile);

// get the new source file text and reparse it to a new AST
const oldText = sourceFile.text;
const newText = oldText.substring(0, objectLiteralExpression.getStart(sourceFile, true))
    + newNodeText + oldText.substring(objectLiteralExpression.end);
const newSourceFile = ts.createSourceFile("file.ts", newText, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, false);

// outputs: `const a = { foo: "bar", can: "haz" };`
console.log(newText);
```

If you are wanting to do this when emitting, then look at providing a custom transformer to `Program#emit(...)`.